# How do I modify the appearance of subsection headings without also messing up how subsection referencing works?

Tags: sectioning, labels, revtex

I have a revtex4 document and I'd like to change how the labels for the subsections appear:

```
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
```

Currently compiles to something like:

> I. Foo
>        A. Bar

But I'd like it to appear as:

> I. Foo
>     I.A Bar

I can do this without too much trouble by adding a new command:
`\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}`

But this messses up how references to sections/subsections appear in the text. If I label them as sec:Foo and subsec:Bar then if I write:

```
lots of stuff happens in section \ref{sec:Foo}
and specifically this interesting thing appears in \ref{subsec:Bar}
```

then that is compiled to:

> lots of stuff happens in section I and specifically this interesting
>   thing happens appears in  I I.A

But I'd like it to appear as:

> lots of stuff happens in section I and specifically this interesting
>   thing happens appears in I.A

I feel like I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too, but it isn't working out. I feel like there is something deeper that I'm missing about how the section numbering/labelling commands work that I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: `revtex4-1` is for submissions to some journals; if you change the layout, the journal's copy editors won't be happy and this may even cause rejection of the paper.

Comment: Indeed! But for whatever reason my advisor has strong feelings about the way things look in the draft process, so I was just going to make a parallel branch with the formatting that they like while we're working on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `revtex4` class adds a prefix to the cross-references to subsections since it uses

```
\def\p@subsection{\thesection\,}
```

so, in addition to

```
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
```

you will also need

```
\def\p@subsection{}
```

to suppress the prefix:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\makeatletter
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testsec}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\label{sec:testsubsec}

Cross reference to the section~\ref{sec:testsec} and to the subsection~\ref{sec:testsubsec}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the class does something similar for other sectional units, as you can see for subsections:

```
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\p@subsubsection{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,}
```

then you might also need to add something like

```
\def\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\p@subsubsection{}
```

(and something similar for lower units) if you want to keep the same style for lower sectional units.

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\makeatletter
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection{}
\def\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\p@subsubsection{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testsec}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\label{sec:testsubsec}
\subsubsection{Test subsection}
\label{sec:testsubsubsec}

Cross reference to the section~\ref{sec:testsec}, to the subsection~\ref{sec:testsubsec} and to the subsubsection~\ref{sec:testsubsubsec}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. The key part I was missing was revtex pre-fix. Thank you!